get values of a line, suggestion about performance
I have code in bash scripting to extract some values in variables.
Text is:
ct: I al: 3669619 dc: SERVERA mn: CAR or: 19qrh sv: R st: Not_Noticed stt: 2024
0411151219 lu: lt: ms: THAT'S MESAGE run_as: USER sb
: TRADE ap: APPLICATION. jb: JDFSSS ho: HOSTA al: R closed_from_em: nb:
cn: 00000000001

Text is a trap that send to a script, so all the line it pass like argument.
My code is:
line=$(echo $*)
jo=$(echo $* | awk '{print $6":"$9}')
dc=$(echo $* | awk '{print $6}')
aid=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* al:\(.*\) dc.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
or=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* or:\(.*\) sv.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
jb=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* jb:\(.*\) ho.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
ms=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* ms:\(.*\) run_as.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
callType=$(echo $* | sed 's/ct:\(.*\) al.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
sv=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* sv:\(.*\) st.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
st=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* st:\(.*\) stt.*/\1/'|  sed 's/^ //g')
sendTime=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* stt:\(.*\) lu.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
ru=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* run_as:\(.*\) sb.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
sb=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* sb:\(.*\) ap.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
ap=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* ap:\(.*\) jb.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
ho=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* ho:\(.*\) al.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')
al=$(echo $* | sed 's/.* al:\(.*\) closed_from.*/\1/' | sed 's/^ //g')

Problem is I execute these code a lot of times simultaneously and I need to improve the performance.
Do you know how to modify code to improve perfomance?
Thanks

Are multiple inputs being processed simultaneously? What does this code have to do with "increasing performance" specifically? Is this a general question about how to process tasks in parallel?

You run a subshell to populate each variable. In some subshells, you run several commands in a pipe. Using parameter expansion might be much faster as it stays in the same shell (but doesn't have all the capabilities of awk or sed).

I'm confused by line=$(echo $*). Is your input 1 line of text or multiple lines of text as shown in your question? Is your tool being called with that input as arguments as implied by `line=$(echo $*)`` or does it read it from a file or pipe? Please [edit] your question to show how the code currently present in it is called as I strongly suspect that's a better way to do THAT as well as solve the problem you're asking about.

Also state whether or not your input always contains all of those fields and, if so, if they're always in that order.

the input (as presented in the question) is spread across 4 lines (ie, the data includes 3 embedded linefeeds); because of the embedded linefeeds your code does not actually work (eg, sb ends up being empty); I'm assuming your input is actually one long line of text; please update the question to confirm the structure and format of the sample input ... multiple lines? one single/long line?

Instead of running several commands in a subshell to populate each variable, use Parameter Expansion. It happens in the same shell, which means it's much faster. It's not as powerful as sed or awk, but fortunately, you don't need it here:
#! /bin/bash
while read line ; do
    set -- $line
    jo=$6:$9
    dc=$6
    aid=${line#* al: };       aid=${aid% dc:*}
    or=${line#* or: };        or=${or% sv:*}
    jb=${line#* jb: };        jb=${jb% ho:*}
    ms=${line#* ms: };        ms=${ms% run_as*}
    callType=${line#ct: };    callType=${callType%% al:*}
    sv=${line#* sv: };        sv=${sv% st:*}
    st=${line#* st: };        st=${st% stt:*}
    sendTime=${line#* stt: }; sendTime=${sendTime% lu:*}
    ru=${line#* run_as: };    ru=${ru% sb:*}
    sb=${line#* sb: };        sb=${sb% ap:*}
    ap=${line#* ap: };        ap=${ap% jb:*}
    ho=${line#* ho: };        ho=${ho% al:*}
    al=${line##* al: };       al=${al% closed_from*}

    echo "JO: $jo."
    echo "DC: $dc."
    echo "AID: $aid."
    echo "OR: $or."
    echo "JB :$jb."
    echo "MS: $ms."
    echo "CALLTYPE: $callType."
    echo "SV: $sv."
    echo "ST: $st."
    echo "SENDTIME: $sendTime."
    echo "RU: $ru."
    echo "SB: $sb."
    echo "AP: $ap."
    echo "HO: $ho."
    echo "AL: $al."
done

